# How use option Kd Ks Ka

Tags: c++, opengl

how use/draw "Kd Ka Ks"?

I am interested in how to use these options.

```
Ks[3]
Kd[3]
Ka[3]

glcolor3f(..., ..., ...);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are coefficients of reflection. Ka is for ambient component, Kd is for diffuse component, and Ks is for specular component.

The Ks, Kd, and Ka are arrays of 3 elements (you can also have a 4th value, the alpha component).  The elements represent the RGB colors.  You can tweak these values if you want to modify how light reflects off of your surface (increase Ks for more specular lighting and making your surface more shiny, Kd for more diffuse reflection, and Ka for more ambient light, which will make everything brighter).

For example, you can modify materials using `glMaterialfv`:

```
GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat shinyness[] = { 5.0 };

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shinyness);
```

Answer (score 2):

S, D, and A should stand for specular, diffuse, and ambient lighting. Without surrounding code though I'm not too sure what the vectors represent. I would guess though that that is the color of the specular, ambient, and diffuse lights to be applied to the surface. There are many shading models you can check out to implement lighting, have a look at Phong: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut11%20Phong%20Model.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading

Comment: Nice guess. And `K` stands for _kolor_, I presume.